# TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload' ,but already have this argument

Tags: python, discord.py

This program should give a user a role if user react to a message

```
    @a.listen()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self,payload):
        print(payload.emoji)
        print(payload.member)
        cba='<:emoji_9:918358779567960094>'
        if str(payload.emoji)==cba:
            print("yz")
            guild=self.a.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
            abc=guild.get_role(925040721692606515)
            await payload.member.add_roles(abc)
```

I noticed that line343 was not in my code

here is line343

```
    def is_ready(self):
        """:class:`bool`: Specifies if the client's internal cache is ready for use."""
        return self._ready.is_set()

    async def _run_event(self, coro, event_name, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            await coro(*args, **kwargs)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
        except Exception:
            try:
                await self.on_error(event_name, *args, **kwargs)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass
    enter code here
```

error messages

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Is that the full traceback error?   Where is this ```on_raw_reaction_add()``` being called?

Comment: thanks for welcome.This is the full traceback error.when user add the reaction at discord,it will be call.

Comment: Is `on_raw_reaction_add` in a Cog?

Comment: I not use cog in this program

Comment: Not being familiar with how discord works, I'm guessing the _run_event() method calls the command ```on_raw_reaction_add()``` with specific parameters as stated in both ```*args``` and ```**kwargs```.  If there aren't any parameters included in the call, it errors.   How is ```on_raw_reaction_add``` triggered?

Comment: To trigger on_raw_reaction_add, the user needs to react to the message, and all messages will trigger this procedure as long as they have a reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you probably copied the code. Your `on_raw_reaction_add` has the arguments `self` and `payload`, while the argument `self` should only be used in classes, or in cogs for discord.py. Because there is the `self` argument and the function is called with `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)`, python thinks that `payload` is `self` and the other `payload` is missing.

So to fix that, simply remove the `self` argument from `on_raw_reaction_add` in your code.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful!!!It finally works